# Completely remove other user's folder from Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I used `Open Other User's Folder` some time ago but I now want to completely remove it from my Outlook profile as it causes my Outlook file to hit the 50GB limit.

To try to remove it, I:

- Right-clicked the folder in the sidebar and selecting `Close "Other Folder"`

  - It appears to be just hidden rather than removed from my file
- After that, in Control Panel, I deleted my entire Outlook profile

  - When starting Outlook, it asked my for my details just like it was run on a fresh installation
  - Outlook started syncing my main folders

The next day, I got the 50GB limit error again and the folder was back.

How can I completely remove the folder so it is as if I never tried `Open Other User's Folder`?

Answer (score 1):

**You need to have your system administrator revoke your permissions to the other user's mailbox.** According to the Microsoft Office support article [Access another person's mailbox](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-another-person-s-mailbox-A909AD30-E413-40B5-A487-0EA70B763081):

> If you are using Outlook 2013, the mailbox for which you have been granted access automatically display in your folder list.

*Note that the article also applies to Outlook 2016.*

Even if you remove the other user's folder manually, Outlook will automatically add it back to your profile again.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.